# Custom hardware support for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, fpga

Tensorflow currently has support for CPU and GPU devices, adding a new device seems possible but the documentation is out of date. The most recent activity on this seems to be from git hub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4359

Is there more current documentation or is there a best practice for adding a device? Has anyone been through the process of adding custom ML hardware under tensorflow?

Comment: That's my question too, we can work together if you're interested in sharing knowledge. Let me know. Thanks.